# M2 - Not creating nl_NL.csv in static files

Tags: magento2.3, csv, translate

I'm running Magento 2 in developer mode, but I need to translate the error message:

> Provided Zip/Postal Code seems to be invalid. Example: 1234 AB/1234AB. If you believe it is the right one you can ignore this notice.

So I created the string in app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/i18n/nl_NL.csv

I run the following commands:

> 1. bin/magento setup:upgrade
> 2. bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f nl_NL
> 3. bin/magento cache:flush
> 4. bin/magento cache:clean

After that I wait till the static files will be created and look into:
pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/nl_NL/i18n

And there is only 1 file: en_US.csv and **not** nl_NL.csv

How is that possible? Is there another way to translate that string?

UPDATE:
It's registered in vendor/magento/language-nl_nl/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,'magento_nl_nl', __DIR__);
```

Magento version: 2.3.0

Comment: Have you registered your language file?

Comment: @aravind Yes, it's in vendor/magento/language-nl_nl/registration.php

Comment: To override you need to register your lanugage again in your theme app/i18n/Vendor/nl_nl

Comment: Hi @aravind, I have no idea how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

app/i18n/DesignVendor/nl_nl/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'designvendor_nl_nl',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/i18n/DesignVendor/nl_nl/language.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>nl_NL</code>
    <vendor>designvendor</vendor>
    <package>nl_nl</package>
</language>
```

Then You can copy your csv file from vendor and paste in

> app/i18n/DesignVendor/nl_nl/nl_NL.csv

You can download module from [here](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack)